# Azure iOS Mobile Client: The server did not return the expected item

Tags: ios, node.js, azure

I'm updating the example Todo app from Microsoft Azure Mobile Services for iOS to use Table Storage instead of the default MSSQL backend.  At the moment, when I try to insert a new item, I am getting the following error in the client:

```
2014-11-22 11:06:44.895 xxx[6942:869598] ERROR Error Domain=com.Microsoft.WindowsAzureMobileServices.ErrorDomain Code=-1201 "The server did not return the expected item." UserInfo=0x7a6b1040 {NSLocalizedDescription=The server did not return the expected item., com.Microsoft.WindowsAzureMobileServices.ErrorResponseKey=<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7a764cc0> { URL: https://xxx.azure-mobile.net/tables/TodoItem } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Length" = 126;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Sat, 22 Nov 2014 19:06:44 GMT";
    Server = "Microsoft-IIS/8.0";
    Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
    "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
    "x-zumo-version" = "Zumo.master.0.1.6.4100.Runtime";
} }, com.Microsoft.WindowsAzureMobileServices.ErrorRequestKey=<NSMutableURLRequest: 0x7a7797a0> { URL: https://xxx.azure-mobile.net/tables/TodoItem }}
```

I have not changed the client code.  The docs at https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/master/sdk/iOS/src/MSJSONSerializer.m suggest that this error is an 'errorForExpectedItem' error, and it gets thrown in itemFromData:withOriginalItem:ensureDictionary:orError:.

This error started happening as I was trying to get the todoitem.read.js script to work; I am so far unable to get usable entities back from that script.  Here's my todoitem.read.js as it now stands:

```
var azure = require('azure-storage');
var tableSvc = azure.createTableService();


function read(query, user, request) {

    query = new azure.TableQuery()
      .select()
      .where('PartitionKey eq ?', 'learningazure');
    console.log('query: ', query);

    tableSvc.queryEntities('TodoItem',query, null, function(error, result, response) {
        if(!error) {
            // query was successful
            // add the count to the response dictionary
            response.count = response.body.value.length;
            response.results = result.entries;
            request.respond(200, response);
        } else {
            console.log('Error calling read()');
            console.log(error);
        }
    });

}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Derp.  My error: in todoitem.insert.js, in the insert() function, I was never calling request.respond().

Now the node.js code is returning data, but it's still not showing up in the iOS client.  More reading required.

Comment: if you find out how to return data to the iOS client, please share! Would be much appreciated. :D